# What is the bottleneck for validate_email?

Tags: python, email, email-spam, mx-record

I'm in the planning stages of a potential project. I would be using [validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email) with a list of addresses. How quickly would I be able to validate the addresses in the list and what would be the bottleneck? Also, am I likely to run into any problems with my ISP, like them thinking I am spamming?

Comment: If you check mx records, this requires a dns lookup, which is a network operation and thus likely to be the slowest/highest latency part of the operation. Your ISP may have limits on DNS queries - but this isn't that likely. Note that this is probably too broad a question for stackoverflow...

Comment: @match Fair enough about not being a great question for Stack Overflow, but I couldn&#39;t think of a better place to ask...

So what you&#39;re saying is that the time to run through the entire list would be determined by the response time of my selected DNS server? Does validate_email automatically use the DNS server configured for my system?

Answer (score 0):

The slowest point is likely to be the DNS lookup for `validate_email`, since this is a network request with associated latency. These lookups may also be throttled by your ISP, though most ISPs don't do much to restrict DNS - apart from perhaps limit which servers you can connect to.

The [`validate_email` documentation](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email) says that it requires [`pyDNS`](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/docs.html) - the `validate_email` code looks like it will not try to do any MX record lookups if this module isn't installed, so one option is to just not install it.

Looking at the code for `pyDNS` it appears to try to get DNS info from `/etc/resolv.conf` on linux/unix/mac, or from the Windows registry - so yes it will use your locally configured DNS servers for the MX lookups.